# finding the angle $\alpha$

Tags: geometry

I am studying for an exam and I really have problems solving tasks like these. The angle $\alpha$ has to be found. I thought about drawing a line from $\alpha$ to $2\alpha$ and then finding the size of the angle through the triangles. But no try works out. Has anyone please got a hint or a solution? I would be very thankful.

[image]

Comment: it says nothing in the task again...but it could help that, if theres a radius and a tangent touching, then the the angle in between is 90 degress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Draw the radii from the points of tangency.  You should have a theorem that tells you at the center based on the angle $2\alpha$.  What is the angle between the radius and the tangent?

Comment: this one should be 90 degrees.. i think its a defintion, if tangent and radius touch, its 90 degrees

Comment: @Sophia:  90 degrees is correct.  It is a theorem about circles, not a definition.  How about the angle between the radii?

Comment: it doesnt say that unfortunatelly

Comment: @Sophia:  but you should be able to use the information from the angle $2\alpha$ to figure it out.  Note that the sides of the $2\alpha$ angle hit the circle at the points of tangency and the vertex of the angle is on the circle.

Comment: if i draw a line from 2 alpha to alpha. can i say the line divides the big anlge (2alpha) into equal parts? half of two alpha, so alpha again?

Comment: @Sophia: no, that would only be true if the $2\alpha$ point were on a straight line with the center of the circle and the $\alpha$ point.  The theorem I was referring to says the angle at the center is twice the angle at the circumference, so the angle between the radii is $4 \alpha$.  Now you have a quadrilateral with angles $90, 90, \alpha, 4\alpha$

Comment: oki I understood the solution above too!  now its 36 degrees. thank you for help!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $P$ and $Q$ be the points where the two tangents meet the circle.

Draw (important) the lines from the centre of the circle to the points of tangency.

Let $R$ be the point where the angle $2\alpha$ is.

Note that you can **move** the point $R$ without changing the angle at $R$ ("angle subtended by a chord.")

So **move it** to a nice point, the most symmetrical one.

Now start "chasing angles," filling in everything in terms of $\alpha$.

After a while you should be able to exploit the fact that a radius meets the tangent line at right angles to get a relationship that leads to $\alpha=36^\circ$.

Comment: oh thank you again andre nicolas! no I am just hard thinking about what you wrote by "chasing angles".. so the whole figure is symmetric now?

Comment: ahhhh i understand!!  thank you for help. 36 is right. now I am happy!